# How can I scale an SVG coordinate system without scaling fonts?

Tags: html, svg

I'm making a data visualization like so:

[image]

and it would be convenient to use `viewBox` to scale the SVG so that the width of the graphic is scaled to be the width of the data range.

My data point in this example is 12,549, and so I want the range to run from 0 to 14,000, and render this in a `viewBox` of width 14,000 using a `rect` of width 12,549. In other words, to use natural units for my data.

But when I do this, the font on my axis **also** scales, and a 10px font also scales, and becomes so small that it can't be seen.

So what I need is a way to scale the drawing units without scaling the font units, but I can't see a way to do this.

## Update

Here is the code in question:

```html
<svg width="960" height="50" class="bullet2" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 14000 25" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="25" class="bars">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="14000" height="25" class="background"/>
<rect x="0" y="0" height="12.5" width="12549" class="item player"/>
<rect x="0" y="12.5" height="12.5" width="3750" class="item team-average"/>
<line x1="2000" x2="2000" y1="0" y2="25" class="marker" style="stroke-width: 29.1667px;"/>
  </svg>
  <g class="axis">
<g transform="translate(0, 25)" class="tick" style="opacity: 1;">
  <line y1="0" y2="5"/>
  <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="6">0</text>
</g>
<g transform="translate(140, 25)" class="tick" style="opacity: 1;">
  <line y1="0" y2="5"/>
  <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="6">2000</text>
</g>
<g transform="translate(280, 25)" class="tick" style="opacity: 1;">
  <line y1="0" y2="5"/>
  <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="6">4000</text>
</g>
<g transform="translate(420, 25)" class="tick" style="opacity: 1;">
  <line y1="0" y2="5"/>
  <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="6">6000</text>
</g>
<g transform="translate(560, 25)" class="tick" style="opacity: 1;">
  <line y1="0" y2="5"/>
  <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="6">8000</text>
</g>
<g transform="translate(700, 25)" class="tick" style="opacity: 1;">
  <line y1="0" y2="5"/>
  <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="6">10000</text>
</g>
<g transform="translate(840, 25)" class="tick" style="opacity: 1;">
  <line y1="0" y2="5"/>
  <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="6">12000</text>
</g>
<g transform="translate(980, 25)" class="tick" style="opacity: 1;">
  <line y1="0" y2="5"/>
  <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="6">14000</text>
</g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Note the `viewBox` on the inner `svg` element scaling it as described. I tried this with the same scaling on the outer `svg` element, which also includes the axis, but when I do this, the image looks like this:

[image]

The axis labels are there, but they are **also** scaled, and a 10px font out of a 14000 pixel scaling is so small that you can't see it.

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to your question. I recommend reading about [SVGPoint](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#InterfaceSVGPoint) and `createSVGPoint`. I consider especially useful the information found in this book: [Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5: Vector Graphics for Web Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076HZ31YZ)

```js
function init(){
  // a function called on resize
  // the function get the new font-size and set the new value of the "font-size"
  let fontSize = 25;
  let newSize = getValue(fontSize);
  // reset the font size
  theText.setAttributeNS(null,"font-size",newSize.x)
}


setTimeout(function() {
  init();
  addEventListener('resize', init, false);
}, 15);


// a function used to recalculate the font size on resize
function getValue(size){
var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
p.x = size;
p.y = 0;
p = p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
return p
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 100">
  <line x1="50" x2="950" y1="50" y2="50" stroke-width="20" stroke="skyblue" />
  
  <line x1="500" x2="500" y1="30" y2="70" stroke-width="1" stroke="#999" />
  <text id="theText"  dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" x="500" y="85" font-size="16" >middle</text>
</svg>
```

## Update

> Can you explain how this solution works?

There are comments in the code. I'm also adding a quote from [Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5: Vector Graphics for Web Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076HZ31YZ):

> Every SVG element that can take a transform [....] has a getScreenCTM() method. The CMT stands for *cumulative transformation matrix*. The screen CMT [....] defines how you can convert points in that element coordinate system back into the original,  unscaled, untransformed coordinate system of the document window. It includes transformations on this element and it's ancestors plus viewBox scaling.

I hope this is useful. However I think you need to read the whole chapter 18 in the book to fully understand the code.

Comment: Can you explain how this solution works? (code blocks without explanation are not that helpful)

Comment: I've updated the answer with a quote from the book that I consider relevant

Comment: Thanks. I am not the OP `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

> **Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).**

There are two approaches to your vague/general scaling problem:

- 1) Put the scaling SVG inside a container SVG? Stacking; and never scale the container which houses the fonts, relative to the percentage of the *child* SVG within.
- 2) It [states here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/font-size) that fonts can be scaled using absolute `px` or relative `em` units. Please see [here for valid length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Content_type#Length).

  I do not see if the `rem` unit can be set, but if so, try if that works?

(I work with SVGs on occassion and CSS a lot, so there may be gaps in my suggestions)